# Question about .profile generated by ubuntu 11.04

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I noticed the following lines at the bottom of my `~/.profile` that was generated from when I installed Ubuntu 11.04:

```
# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

I see the logic there, but shouldn't the PATH variable be exported?

```
# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    export PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

If not, then I don't understand how the value of PATH does not get lost once the bottom of the `.profile` file is reached, unless something is sourcing this file with `. ~/.profile`, which I do not see (at least explicitly) happening in any other shell script on the system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a variable is already exported, you don't have to export it again. And yes, the shell does (the moral equivalent of) source `.profile` when you start a login shell (unless you also have a `.bash_profile`; but then that should customarily source `.profile` in turn).